# I have a .gz folder that I want to decompress using gunzip from the command line, but it shows the following error. "File too large". Please help

Tags: command-line

I have a .gz folder that I want to decompress using gunzip from the command line, but it shows the following error. "File too large". Please help

Comment: Please check this link http://blog.ataboydesign.com/2013/06/06/aix-gzip-file-too-large-error.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))